# Categorical Principal Component Analysis

Tags: pca, ordinal-data, categorical-data, optimal-scaling

I am planning to perform a Categorical Principal Component Analysis, I have 14 variables with categorical ordinal data (from a 5 point likert scale) and one variable with categorical nominal data. What optimal scaling level should I use?

Comment: What do you mean "optimal scale"? It may help you to read: [Can principal component analysis be applied to datasets containing a mix of continuous and categorical variables?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5774/7290)

Comment: On this site, there is a number of answers about CatPCA and optimal scaling. Please make a search first. Among others, [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15580/3277) thread is important. [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41176/3277) is a few practical recommendations (at least for SPSS).

Comment: search also this site for multiple correspondence analysis

Comment: Possible dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/doing-principal-component-analysis-or-factor-analysis-on-binary-data,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data